# Problema com cadastros (Column count doesn't match value count at row 1)

Tags: java, mysql

Estou tendo o erro "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" quando tento efetuar um cadastro. Já verifiquei meu BD e tudo parece estar em ordem mas nada de conseguir resolver esse erro.

Meu código de cadastro.

```
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("actionPerformed()"); 
            // captura valor de radiobuttons
            String consignacao;
            if (consig_sim.isSelected()) {
                consignacao = consig_sim.getText();
            } else {
                consignacao = consig_nao.getText();
            }
            // /fim da captura
            String Cadastro = ("insert into livros (ISBN, titulo_livro, autor_livro, editora_livro, consignacao, preco, quantidade) values ('"
                    + jTextField.getText()
                    + ", "
                    + jTextField1.getText()
                    + ","
                    + jTextField2.getText()
                    + ", "
                    + jTextField3.getText()
                    + ", "
                    + consignacao
                    + ", "
                    + jTextField4.getText()
                    + ", "
                    + jTextField5.getText() + "')");
            try {
                cadastro.Executar("select * from livros");
                cadastro.stm.executeUpdate(Cadastro); //de acordo com o eclipse o erro esta acontecendo aqui
                cadastro.stm.close();
                cadastro.Executar("select * from livros");
                JOptionPane
                        .showMessageDialog(null, "Cadastro efetuado");
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

classe Query.

```
package modulo;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Query {
public static Object resultset;
public Statement stm;
public ResultSet Resultado;
private boolean conectado = false;

static Conexao data_base = new Conexao();

public ResultSet Executar(String Sql) {

    try {
        if (!conectado) {
            data_base.conectar();
            conectado = true;
        }
        stm = data_base.con.createStatement();
        Resultado = stm.executeQuery(Sql);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    }
    return Resultado;
}

}
```

Comment: Ele está dizendo que o número de colunas passadas não está batendo. Você já verificou se está passando todos os valores que está definido na query?

Comment: Verifiquei sim, inclusive através do Debug ele mostra que todos os dados estão sendo passados corretamente.

Comment: O resultado do Debug esta assim: INSERT INTO livros (ISBN, titulo_livro, autor_livro, editora_livro, consignacao, preco, quantidade) VALUES ('111111111', 'teste','teste','teste','Não','1.34','1')

Comment: Já testou o que o @Tony sugeriu abaixo? Funcionou?

Comment: Acabei de testar, o erro persiste.

Comment: Se possível, adicione a mensagem de erro.

Comment: Então, refiz o teste e o cadastro foi efetuado corretamente, porém no console apareceu a seguinte mensagem: ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183):  [../../../src/share/back/util.c:838]

Comment: Este erro não parece ser relacionado ao MySQL. Talvez algum colega mais entendido esclareça isto.

Answer (score 5):

Você delimitou todas as variáveis da query com um único par de aspas simples.

```
String Cadastro = ("
    insert into livros (
        ISBN,
        titulo_livro,
        autor_livro,
        editora_livro,
        consignacao,
        preco,
        quantidade)
    values ('" +
        jTextField.getText() + ", " +
        jTextField1.getText() + "," +
        jTextField2.getText() + ", " +
        jTextField3.getText() + ", " +
        consignacao + ", " +
        jTextField4.getText() + ", " +
        jTextField5.getText() + "')");
```

Para corrigir, deixe assim:

```
String Cadastro = ("
    insert into livros (
        ISBN,
        titulo_livro,
        autor_livro,
        editora_livro,
        consignacao,
        preco,
        quantidade)
    values ('" +
        jTextField.getText() + "', '" +
        jTextField1.getText() + "', '" +
        jTextField2.getText() + "', '" +
        jTextField3.getText() + "', '" +
        consignacao + "', '" +
        jTextField4.getText() + "', '" +
        jTextField5.getText() + "')");
```

Comment: PS: minha primeira correção tinha um erro de digitação, já arrumei. :)

Answer (score 4):

Para ficar correto o código precisa levar em conta os parâmetros, pois às vezes vem caracteres especiais, como o apóstrofo '
Dê uma estudada no [Java SQL Parameters](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=Java+SQL+Parameters)

TODO: [MySQL Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12745238/194717)

Para 'fazer funcionar', tente mudar seu código para:

```
String Cadastro = ("INSERT INTO livros (ISBN, titulo_livro, autor_livro, editora_livro, consignacao, preco, quantidade) VALUES ('"
                + jTextField.getText().replace("'","''")
                + "', '"
                + jTextField1.getText().replace("'","''")
                + "','"
                + jTextField2.getText().replace("'","''")
                + "','"
                + jTextField3.getText().replace("'","''")
                + "','"
                + consignacao.replace("'","''")
                + "','"
                + jTextField4.getText().replace("'","''")
                + "','"
                + jTextField5.getText().replace("'","''") + "')");
```

Comment: Mudei meu código como sugerido mas não resolveu, continua com o mesmo erro.

Comment: Você poderia colocar na pergunta o SQL que foi gerado desta concatenação? E a mensagem exata do erro?

Comment: Executei o cadastro e ele gerou o seguinte código: INSERT INTO livros (ISBN, titulo_livro, autor_livro, editora_livro, consignacao, preco, quantidade) VALUES ('111111111', 'teste','teste','teste','Não','1.34','1')

Comment: O campos são todos string/char no banco de dados? Coloque também o erro/Exception que aparece.

Comment: Valeu @Tony, utilizando o código sugerido por você e refazendo os testes foi possível efetuar o cadastro. Agora me resta descobrir o que significa essa mensagem: ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183):  [../../../src/share/back/util.c:838].

Comment: Sobre este erro, referência em Inglês http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225737/error-jdwp-unable-to-get-jni-1-2-environment

Answer (score 4):

O erro diz que a quantidade de colunas é diferente do número de valores passados na clausula `VALUES`. Da forma como está o codigo existem 7 colunas e apenas uma valor, pois apenas uma aspa simples foi colocada no inicio da sql e outra no final.

```
INICIO--v
values ('"+ jTextField.getText()+ ", "+jTextField1.getText()+","+ jTextField2.getText()
          + ", "+ jTextField3.getText()+ ", "+ consignacao+ ", "+ jTextField4.getText()
          + ", "+ jTextField5.getText() + "')");
                                           ^------FIM
```

Para previnir seu código contra ataques de sql injection e não se perder nesse mar de virgulas aspas simples e deixar a sql mais simples utilize prepares statements.

```
String Cadastro = "INSERT INTO livros (ISBN, titulo_livro, autor_livro, 
editora_livro,"+ "consignacao, preco, quantidade) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

PreparedStatement stmt = cadastro.prepareStatement(Cadastro); 
stmt.setString(1, jTextField.getText());
stmt.setString(2, jTextField1.getText());
stmt.setString(3, jTextField2.getText());
stmt.setString(4, jTextField3.getText());
stmt.setString(5, consignacao);
stmt.setString(6, jTextField4.getText());
stmt.setString(7, jTextField5.getText());

stmt.execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

Galera consegui resolver o problema aqui, minha classe DAO estava mandando dentro do metodo adicionar a seguinte string "String sql = "insert into contatos values (?,?,?,?)";"
alterei para "String sql = "insert into contatos (nome,email,endereco,dataNascimento)values (?,?,?,?)";", basicamente o problema era referente ao objeto da classe java.sql.Date

```
package br.com.caelum.servlet.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import br.com.caelum.servlet.jdbc.ConnectionFactory;
import br.com.caelum.servlet.modelo.Contatos;

public class ContatosDAO {

    private Connection con;

    public ContatosDAO(){
        con = new ConnectionFactory().getConnection();
    }

    public void adicionar(Contatos contato) {

        String sql = "insert into contatos (nome,email,endereco,dataNascimento)values (?,?,?,?)";
        try {

            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);

            ps.setString(1, contato.getNome());
            ps.setString(2, contato.getEmail());
            ps.setString(3, contato.getEndereco());
            ps.setDate(4, new Date(contato.getDataNascimento().getTimeInMillis()));
            ps.execute();
            ps.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            throw new RuntimeException();
        } 

    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Aconteceu o mesmo comigo e após muitos testes descobri um erro no Trigger (after insert) da tabela em questão, após corrigir o erro do Trigger esse erro não mais aconteceu.